# magento 2 order confirmation email sending before payment gatway redirection

Tags: magento2, cart, payment-gateway, order-email

I am new to magento2 and developing a custom payment module for ccavenue.I am facing a problem regarding order confirmation email.

The order confirmation email is sending once the customer redirecting to payment gateway page and order is creating with pending status.I want to send this email after a successful transaction.

Here is my payment js code

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
    'mage/url',
],
function (
    $,
    Component,
    placeOrderAction,
    selectPaymentMethodAction,
    customer,
    checkoutData,
    additionalValidators,
    url) {


        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Magekmf_Ccavenue/payment/ccavenue'
            },
            placeOrder: function (data, event) {
                if (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
                var self = this,
                    placeOrder,
                    emailValidationResult = customer.isLoggedIn(),
                    loginFormSelector = 'form[data-role=email-with-possible-login]';
                if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                    $(loginFormSelector).validation();
                    emailValidationResult = Boolean($(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').valid());
                }
                if (emailValidationResult && this.validate() && additionalValidators.validate()) {
                    this.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(false);
                    placeOrder = placeOrderAction(this.getData(), true, this.messageContainer);

                    $.when(placeOrder).fail(function () {
                        self.isPlaceOrderActionAllowed(true);
                    }).done(this.afterPlaceOrder.bind(this));
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            },

            selectPaymentMethod: function() {
                selectPaymentMethodAction(this.getData());
                checkoutData.setSelectedPaymentMethod(this.item.method);
                return true;
            },

            afterPlaceOrder: function () {
                window.location.replace(url.build('ccavenue/request'));
            },
            /** Returns send check to info */
            getMailingAddress: function() {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            }


        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Show more detail with code.

Comment: What type of integration do you use? It seems you call wrong Web API entry point from your payment js component. Seems you need to call `set-payment-information`, but you calls `payment-information` (this is default action), but anyway you need to provide more details.

Comment: @joni i have edited my question.Please check

Comment: @renjith, as I assumed in the previous comment, you need to call `set-payment-information` instead `payment-information` (`placeOrder` method) after that, redirect customer to external payment provider and when customer comes back to Magento store - call `payment-information` action (`placeOrder` method)

Comment: @joni Can you provide any reference link.Thanks.

Comment: @renjith, what kind of reference link? Magento dev docs do not describe your case because it's not typical. But Magento EE contains few payments with a similar flow.

Comment: @jonijones .. so need to change this function placeOrder: function (data, event)  ?

Comment: You can write own function and bind it in your template and after redirect use `placeOrder` function as is. The similar behavior you can find in Braintree PayPal js component

Comment: @renjith; Can you explain how you resolved this ?

Comment: @jonijones .. Can you help me on this  similar issue: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202001/order-confirmation-email-sent-before-redirecting-to-third-party-payment-gateway

Comment: Use this free extension http://magecomp.com/magento-2-order-confirmation-email.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was facing same issue but I found alternative solution like I turned off Magento default Order Confirmation email and Send Order Confirmation Email When Order is being placed Successfully.

Here are the step to follow :

Create Observer Event which being called after order placed : 
`events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action_sendmail" instance="<vendor_name>\OrderSuccessMail\Observer\SendMailOnOrderSuccess" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Observer: `SendMailOnOrderSuccess.php`

```
<?php

namespace <vendor_name>\OrderSuccessMail\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SendMailOnOrderSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
     */
    protected $orderModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
     */
    protected $orderSender;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderModel
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderModel,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->orderModel = $orderModel;
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        if(count($orderIds))
        {
            $this->checkoutSession->setForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess(true);
            $order = $this->orderModel->create()->load($orderIds[0]);
            $this->orderSender->send($order, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here **$this->orderSender->send($order, true);** called which extends abstract class method() which check if Order confirmation email is enabled from backend or not so we need create plugin for that

`di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity">
        <plugin name="change_is_enable_method" type="\<vendor_name>\OrderSuccessMail\Plugin\Sales\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentityPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

`OrderIdentityPlugin.php`

```
<?php

namespace <vendor_name>\OrderSuccessMail\Plugin\Sales\Order\Email\Container;

class OrderIdentityPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @return bool
     */
    public function aroundIsEnabled(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject, callable $proceed)
    {
        $returnValue = $proceed();

        $forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess = $this->checkoutSession->getForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess();
        if(isset($forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess) && $forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess)
        {
            if($returnValue)
                $returnValue = false;
            else
                $returnValue = true;

            $this->checkoutSession->unsForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess();
        }

        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

Here in above plugin we have checked if confirmation is enabled from backend config or not, If yes then It works as default but if No then our custom email Confirmation order will be sent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. How did you turn off this default email? If i turn off stores -> configuration -> sales -> sales email -> order then no emails will be sent. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I did same setting as you did but I wrote the script  when Backend email is off then my custom code will work. @TanelTammik

Comment: @ Ronak Chauhan can you please share full code when Backend email is off

Comment: @RonakChauhan  can you please share full code when Backend email is off

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It didn't work for me with Magento 2.3.1. It seems that the `isEnabled` method is called more than once, which ends up with never sending an email. Moving the `$this->checkoutSession->unsForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess();` line from `OrderIdentityPlugin.php` to `SendMailOnOrderSuccess.php` right after `$this->orderSender->send($order, true);` solved the problem.

Comment: @Zsolti Sorry, but this answer is not for magento 2.3.*

Comment: thank you so much @Zsolti it fixed my problem, also if someone has code style check on pipelines, here is styled code 
OrderIndentityPlugin

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved by rewriting

```
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender::send
```

function, For that first add the following in your di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="Company\Module\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender"/>
```

and Create class OrderSender with as below

```
namespace Company\Module\Model\Order\Email\Sender;

use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender {

    public function send(Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        $payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();

        if($payment == 'your-payment-method-code'){
            return false;
        }

        $order->setSendEmail(true);

        if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
            if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
                $order->setEmailSent(true);
                $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                return true;
            }
        }

        $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'send_email');

        return false;
    }
}
```

Once you return back to site from payment gateway send confirmation mail manually from your success controller.

Comment: I tried this but its not taking my OrderSender its taking core modules OrderSender

Comment: found it was overriten already by other module

Comment: Hello, this solution is already implemented by ccavenue plugin, using the di code, it will manage the not send mail to the user but the Model file not working fine for ccavenue orders, I checked multiple time there is only override file in my code, please help me out of this stuck? and i am using magento 2.3.2 version

Comment: @PMB...........

Comment: Used this and worked for my project. Used by other module though.

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much @Zsolti it fixed my problem, also if someone has code style check on pipelines, here is styled code 
OrderIndentityPlugin

```
<?php

namespace Devall\OrderSuccess\Plugin\Sales\Order\Email\Container;

class OrderIdentityPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject
     * @param callable $proceed
     * @return bool
     */
    public function aroundIsEnabled(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity $subject,
        callable $proceed
    ) {
        $returnValue = $proceed();

        $forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess = $this->checkoutSession->getForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess();
        if (isset($forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess) && $forceOrderMailSentOnSuccess) {
            if ($returnValue) {
                $returnValue = false;
            } else {
                $returnValue = true;
            }
        }

        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

SendMailOnOrderSuccess

```
<?php

namespace Devall\OrderSuccess\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SendMailOnOrderSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
     */
    protected $orderModel;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
     */
    protected $orderSender;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderModel
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderModel,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {
        $this->orderModel = $orderModel;
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
        if (count($orderIds)) {
            $this->checkoutSession->setForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess(true);
            $order = $this->orderModel->create()->load($orderIds[0]);
            $this->orderSender->send($order, true);
            $this->checkoutSession->unsForceOrderMailSentOnSuccess();
        }
    }
}
```

This answer is for 2.3.*