# customer get order confirmation email before pay

Tags: magento2, payment-gateway, order-email, magento-2.1.9, third-party-plugin

I'm using the third party extensions for payment(Paytm and PayUmoney) for our magento website. the issue is customer get an order confirmation email before Pay when they just redirected.

I made all the changes as this post mentioned ([magento 2 order confirmation email sending before payment gatway redirection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154595/magento-2-order-confirmation-email-sending-before-payment-gatway-redirection)) and its working fine in PayUmoney but not for Paytm.

If I pay through PayUmoney not getting any email before pay but if I pay through Paytm I get order confirmation email before pay.

Website Link- https://oyekitchen.com
version- Magento 2.1.9

Comment: Magento2 will create orders before redirecting to the 3rd party website for payment. Looks like you will need to change the default order status to "Pending" in the Paytm configurations in magento backend.

Comment: can you share some link or code @Nidheesh

Comment: https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-payment-methods/

Comment: I checked but in Paytm New Order status only two options are their 1- Processing, 2- Suspected Fraud. currently I selected Processing @Nidheesh

Comment: @Aayush any solution for it ?